# Django on Heroku - ProgrammingError at / relation "..." does not exist

Tags: django, heroku

I'm getting [this](https://i.gyazo.com/74e3cfa508aead90c449e5784a6c5632.png) error.  I know you usually get this error because the databases wasn't properly migrated.

When I run `heroku local web`, the website works fine when I go to `localhost:5000`.

However after I deploy the app to heroku with `git push heroku master`, the error comes up.

In other words, it works in my local environment.  But it does not work after deploying to heroku.

I have Heroku-Postgres installed as an add-on in heroku.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Did you run `heroku run manage.py migrate`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman That was the issue.  I was doing `python manage.py migrate` and then deploying it, thinking that would work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

excute migrations and makemigrations in bash heroku. open the terminal in the local project folder and give the following commands:

```
heroku run bash
~$  ./manage.py makemigrations
~$  ./manage.py migrate
~$  exit
```

Comment: No, _don't_ run `makemigrations` on Heroku. By the time you're deploying you shouldn't have any model changes that would generate new migrations. Run that _locally_, then commit the migration files. On Heroku you should only run the migrations via `manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps did it for me

1. Make all the necessary migrations (`python manage.py makemigrations`) and migrate (`python manage.py migrate`) locally,
2. push to heroku master
3. and finally running `heroku run python manage.py migrate`

Solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error after making a change to a model and then deploying this change to heroku.

The only way I managed to fix this problem was to do the following:

- Reset the database in heroku
- Delete the migrations files from the migrations folder for the broken app locally (but keep the directory and the `__init__.py` file)
- Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`. This will repopulate the migrations folder with clean migration files.
- Push changes to master (ensure that you do not have migrations directories in `.gitignore` files.
- Deploy changes to heroku
- Run the heroku shell `heroku run bash`
- Run `python manage.py migrate`

I was able to do this because my tables did not have much data in, but I would try to avoid resetting the database if I had more data in my tables.

Comment: May I ask how do I reset the database in heroku?

Comment: It is easily done using the heroku web console. Select your application in dashboard.heroku.com. You'll find the database under add-ons, one of the options there you can use to reset the database.