# django blog error keeps occuring on deployment to heroku

Tags: django, heroku, blogs

<
I am getting the following error when I try open my blog page after deployment to Heroku. it works ok in cloud9 but throws up the error once I deploy it. All the other pages of the site work fine. Can anybody help me please?

[[image: Error Message[1]]

```html
Blog models.py file

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.utils.text import slugify
import datetime

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', default='Upload Picture')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=340)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='post_likes', blank=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def approve_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def get_like_url(self):
        return reverse('like', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_list")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Database from settings.py file

!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

```html
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

if 'DATABASE_URL' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you apply your migrations after deploying?

Comment: yes, i did. It made no difference

Comment: Just to be sure. I've had a similar issue with PyCharm not including migrations in my git commits by default. Can you check with `git status` in your project directory if you've actually submitted the migrations to your codebase?

Comment: The initial migration was sitting there. I did a makemigration and migrate but it made no difference. The same error is coming up in heroku.

Comment: This error only appears if a migration was not applied. Perhaps this thread might help you, specifically with heroku https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083216/django-on-heroku-programmingerror-at-relation-does-not-exist?rq=1

Comment: Don't run `makemigrations` on Heroku. You should be running migrations that you've already created locally and committed, not trying to create new ones. Are you maybe using SQLite instead of PostgreSQL or another client-server database? Please show us your database configuration.

Comment: I have updated to show my databse settings.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. The postgres key in heroku was different to the key I had input locally. I updated locally and now it works. thank you all for your time, help and patience.