# ProgrammingError at /products/ or 500 error when i click to another app in Heroku but it works locally

Tags: django, heroku

My project works locally but i get 500 errors on heroku when trying to press a link to another app which was products in my project. I get this error: `ProgrammingError at /products/ relation "products_product" does not exist LINE 1: ...uct"."image_url", "products_product"."image" FROM "products_...`

Here is the full error log from Heroku:

```
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415919+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415919+00:00 app[web.1]: return compiled_parent._render(context)
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415920+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415920+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.nodelist.render(context)
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415920+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415921+00:00 app[web.1]: bit = node.render_annotated(context)
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415921+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415922+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.render(context)
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415922+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415923+00:00 app[web.1]: result = block.nodelist.render(context)
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415923+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415923+00:00 app[web.1]: bit = node.render_annotated(context)
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415924+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415924+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.render(context)
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415924+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/template/base.py", line 988, in render
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415924+00:00 app[web.1]: output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415924+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/template/base.py", line 698, in resolve
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415925+00:00 app[web.1]: new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415925+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 550, in length
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415925+00:00 app[web.1]: return len(value)
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415925+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/db/models/query.py", line 269, in __len__
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415926+00:00 app[web.1]: self._fetch_all()
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415926+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/db/models/query.py", line 1303, in _fetch_all
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415926+00:00 app[web.1]: self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415926+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415927+00:00 app[web.1]: results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chu
    nked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415932+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415932+00:00 app[web.1]: cursor.execute(sql, params)
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415932+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415933+00:00 app[web.1]: return super().execute(sql, params)
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415933+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415933+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=
    False, executor=self._execute)
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415934+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415934+00:00 app[web.1]: return executor(sql, params, many, context)
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415934+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415934+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415935+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415935+00:00 app[web.1]: raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc
    _value
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415936+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    /django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415936+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415936+00:00 app[web.1]: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "products_
    product" does not exist
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.415937+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...uct"."image_url", "products_product"."imag
    e" FROM "products_...
[19/Feb/2022:01:51:05 +0000] "GET /pro
    ducts/ HTTP/1.1" 500 209364 "https://quickthrift-andregrandon.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macint
    osh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/53
    7.36"
    2022-02-19T01:51:05.420833+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/products/" host=quickth
    rift-andregrandon.herokuapp.com request_id=d2a516ed-3dcb-48cc-99dd-d2a9e2b8d66f fwd="76.69.37.221"
     dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=120ms status=500 bytes=209632 protocol=https"
```

Comment: You've to run makemigrations & migrate command

Comment: @AnkitTiwari, most likely just `migrate`. [Migrations should never be made on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083216/django-on-heroku-programmingerror-at-relation-does-not-exist#comment94440445_48446653).

Comment: Are you using SQLite? This is definitely a duplicate, but I want to find the right one.